# Add to cart Button Animation

Tags: magento-1.9

I need help in Button animation in magento. I simply want my Add to cart button will change when user clicks on the button. Just like http://www.localbanya.com/. When any user will click on add to cart button on catalog page, the button text will be changed as "1 item added to cart". How do I do it. Please help.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

1) You should try coding this yourself first and then ask for help when you get stuck.

2) I'm giving you an idea how to do it as a starting point for your googling. As you can see from that site, when you add to cart there is a `json` call. If the status is `"success"` then change the text of that button with javascript along these lines:

```
if (status == "success"){
  $("button").each(function(){
    $(this).find("span").text("new text here");
  });
}
```

this is just an idea. How it is done depends on your configuration.